# Hot to add { or } symbols in <%= search_url into the head

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our structured data area (in `<head>`) we have this

```
"potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "<%= search_url(search: {q: "{search_term_string}" }) %>",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
}
```

Watch "target". It show me the link in this way

It show me 
`https://www.mywebsite.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bq%5D=%7Bsearch_term_string%7D`

It doesn't show { or } but %7B and %7D

How how to solve?

I already try to fix using

`"{search_term_string}".html_safe`

or

`"&#123;search_term_string&#125;".html_safe`

or

`%({search_term_string})`

or

`%(&#123;search_term_string&#125;).html_safe`

but nothing

Comment: If search_term_string is user a supplied string is user supplied content you should not be calling `.html_safe` on it. Thats how XSS attacks happen.  Instead you want to do. `'{'.html_safe + search_term_string  + '}'.html_safe`. https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong

Comment: search_term_string is not a "variable". It should be showed. I have to show LL {search_term_string} in html - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to produce a template of a URL (not necessarily a valid URL itself but a template that can be used to produce a valid URL). You know exactly what you need to replace, you can be pretty certain that it will only occur in one place, and you know that everything is safe because you're controller everything and GoogleBot knows what it is looking for (presumably).

I'd go ahead and patch up the encoding by hand:

```
search_url(search: { q: "{search_term_string}" }).sub('%7Bsearch_term_string%7D', '{search_term_string}')
```

If you think the pattern will appear more than once (which is highly unlikely), use `gsub` instead of `sub`.

You could also be more explicit about what you're doing:

```
.sub('%7Bsearch_term_string%7D') { |encoded| URI.decode(encoded) }
```

Or put it all in a helper (say `search_url_for_microdata`) so that you can leave a note to your future self about why you're doing this:

```
# Untangle URL encoding issues with json+ld microdata for GoogleBot.
def search_url_for_microdata
  search_url(search: { q: '{search_term_string}' })
    .sub('%7Bsearch_term_string%7D') { |encoded| URI.decode(encoded) }
end
```

or even:

```
# Untangle URL encoding issues with json+ld microdata for GoogleBot.
def search_url_for_microdata
  decoded = '{search_term_string}'
  encoded = URI.encode(decoded)
  search_url(search: { q: decoded }).sub(encoded, decoded)
end
```

or:

```
DECODED = '{search_term_string}'
ENCODED = URI.encode(DECODED)

# Untangle URL encoding issues with application/ld+json microdata for GoogleBot.
def search_url_for_microdata
  search_url(search: { q: DECODED }).sub(ENCODED, DECODED)
end
```